# Visualizing elevation data from WMTS

Tags: qgis, wmts

https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_5M_Elevation/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml is some elevation data of interest to me.

In QGIS, I've set that up as a WMTS layer, but what do I need to do to visualize it, for example as grey scale?

Comment: just to make things clear in case they aren't: a WMTS serves *image* tiles that are pre-rendered on the server; you won't be able to style those tiles (e.g. make it a greyscale when it's not) based on meta data (like elevation), since it's not existent in the images. apart from that, as @nielsgerrits stated, that service doesn't serve anything...

Comment: Thanks for this ... but given https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_5M_Elevation/ImageServer is an "elevation service", surely the elevation info is available to be used somehow?!  What I'd really like to do is compute a viewshed by using this as the DEM for the Visibility Analysis plugin (so visualizing as a grey scale may have been a red herring, sorry).

Comment: I know it seems so logical...but here, 'service' is a resource access and transfer protocol standard, and WMTS only serves *image* tiles, with RGB color values for each pixel. it's absolutely possible to encode elevation info into the RGB range (e.g. Mapbox has a high res DEM encoded Terrain tile service), but you'd need specialized tools to decode and use that data. above that, I doubt ESRI would happily provide a public service with their proprietary (and rather expensive) elevation data, but I wouldn't know. still, you are better off looking for sources to acquire the *meta data* yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a server side issue. The ImageService is probably not cached, so no tiles available.

It does work for the basemap. If you query a raw tile it returns a valid image:
https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Base_Map/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/public_NSW_Base_Map/default/GoogleMapsCompatible/14/9856/15047.png

Where the imageservice returns an empty one:
https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_5M_Elevation/ImageServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/public_NSW_Base_Map/default/GoogleMapsCompatible/14/9856/15047.png